# preparing data for analysis

Tags: r, aggregate

I am new here and very new to R and statistic in general.
I got a simple 1million rows of data in a csv format. There are 4 columns: say 
Col1 - Location
Col2 - Someone's name
Col3 - Date visit
COl4 - Time of visit

When importing it into R they are translated as data frame and all columns are character (I use str() to find the structure of my imported data and class() thats why I know its a data.frame.

As you see none of them are numeric, I want to be able to do some aggregation e.g count number of visits by person, by day, by time by location or vice versa.

Do I need to manipulate data outside R e.g import into SQL and do some aggregation there or can I do this in R?

I hope you can guide me in the right direction... many thanks
Peddie

Comment: You can use the `table()` function to get counts by group. See `?table`

Comment: Look at the `xtabs` function. If you use `tapply` or `aggregate`, the standard method to return counts is to use `length`. @hadley (and others I think) have constructed `count` functions for addon packages.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting familiar with the [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) package.

```
install.packages("plyr")
```

It will ask you to choose a place to download from, just choose the closest one to you. Then load the library

```
library(plyr)
```

Ok so lets say we have data frame that looks like this

```
 > df
    Name  Day Location
52  Jake  Wed       MI
25 Sally  Tue       NY
38   Sue  Fri       NY
45 Sally  Tue       MI
42   Sue  Mon       MI
17 Sally  Fri       CA
28  Jake  Tue       NY
14   Sue Thur       CA
47   Jim  Tue       MI
67   Jim  Tue       AL
```

We can ask how many times each location was visited

```
> ddply(df, .(Location), summarise, count=length(Name))
  Location count
1       CA     2
2       NY     3
3       MI     4
4       AL     1
```

Or how many people visited a location on a particular day

```
> ddply(df, .(Location, Day), summarise, count=length(Name))
  Location  Day count
1       CA Thur     1
2       CA  Fri     1
3       NY  Tue     2
4       NY  Fri     1
5       MI  Mon     1
6       MI  Tue     2
7       MI  Wed     1
8       AL  Tue     1
```

You should look up a thorough tutorial on plyr, but for the commands above what is essentially going on is that ddply is splitting up you data frame by the unique combinations of values in the columns you specify and summarizing your data based on the function (in our case length) that you specify.

I hope this helps.